# Gradle sync failed: 'com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin' does not implement the Plugin interface

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, gradle-plugin, android-studio-plugin

Environment : Android Studio 2.1

Project : Android SDK + Cordova

Android Studio throws the following error during Gradle Sync :

Gradle sync failed: 'com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin' does not implement the Plugin interface

Answer (score 37):

Faced the same issue after upgrading to android studio 2.1 from 1.5

Managed to resolve by updating the dependencies version if the *gradle.gradleVersion >= 2.1* in the **build.gradle** file under buildscript {}

**OLD Configuration**

```
 if (gradle.gradleVersion >= "2.2") {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
} else if (gradle.gradleVersion >= "2.1") {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.0+'
    }
} else {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.0+'
    }
}
```

**Updated Configuration**

```
if (gradle.gradleVersion >= "2.2") {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
} else if (gradle.gradleVersion >= "2.1") {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    }
} else {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.0+'
    }
}
```

If you do not have *if/else clause* in your **build.gradle** you can update the dependencies directly as below,

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
}
```