# failed to run 'forcedroid create' for a hybrid android app

Tags: android, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I am going through salesforce trailhead "Get Started with Hybrid Development".

Now, I try to create a forcedroid hybrid android app with command "forcedroid create".

```
E:\TempTry>forcedroid create

Enter your application type (native, hybrid_remote, or hybrid_local): hybrid_local
Enter your application name: MyTrailHybridLocal
Enter the target directory of your app: TrailHybridApps
Enter the package name for your app (com.mycompany.my_app): com.mytrail.hybrid
```

But I failed and got an error message as below.

> ". Should be in the format x[.y[.ignored]]
>   ) is less than the minimum required version (5.4.0).  Please update your version
>    of Cordova.

In fact, folder TrailHybridApps exists and it is empty. And my Cordova is v6.3.0.

```
E:\TempTry>cordova -v
6.3.0
```

So, what's wrong? And what can I do now?

Thanks in advance.

---

In fact, I have succeeded in finishing a Cordova android app acoording to the guide: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/

So, I think my Cordova has no problem and it seems that the question resulted from the "npm forcedroid". On the other hand, I have not github installed. Does it have anything to do with github?

Comment: I think the error message was some confused because version of my cordova(6.3.0) is greater than required(5.4.0) in fact.
Does it have anything to do with git? I do not have git installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to you all.

At last I worked out this problem. I would like to share with you all here.

1. I think it must be a bug of Cordova V6.3.0 or forcedroid create. 
   Refer to : https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Android/issues/1209
2. As for me, Cordova V6.2.0 works fine while V5.4.0 seemed to result in another error message: Error:'com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin'.
   npm uninstall -g cordova
   npm install -g cordova@6.2.0
3. 'cordova telemetry off' doesn't work for me.

Thanks again, special to Richard W, miken32, Ali Nfr and Rajasekar.

Answer (score 2):

Before running forcedroid create, run this command:

```
cordova telemetry off
```

Then `forcedroid create` should work. Or, you could uninstall Cordova and reinstall with a specific version, i.e.:

```
npm uninstall -g cordova
npm install -g cordova@5.4.0
```

You don't have to do anything with github.

Comment: Thank you.
But the 1st solution does not work. 
After uninstalling the latest version of cordova(6.3.0) and installing V5.4.0, I succeeded in creating the android project. Thank you.

Comment: But now, I got another error message:

Error:'com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin' does not implement the Plugin interface.

Comment: It looks like some other people have been able to manually fix it with these instructions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36925531/gradle-sync-failed-com-android-build-gradle-baseplugin-does-not-implement-the/36978066#36978066

Comment: I'd also recommend you post these questions to the SalesforceMobileSDK Google+ community. That's where the Mobile SDK SMEs hang out. https://plus.google.com/communities/114225252149514546445

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your cordova. [This](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/upgrade.html) guide shows how to modify Android projects to upgrade from older versions of Cordova. Most of these instructions apply to projects created with an older set of command-line tools that precede the cordova CLI utility. See The Command-Line Interface for information on how to update the version of the CLI.

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/upgrade.html

Comment: But my cordova has been the latest version, 6.3.0.
I ran command "npm update -g cordova". And because the "forcedroid create" failed, I have not generated any android project.